# Match on 2 cells and return value from 3rd cell (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel

I have 2 worksheets.

SHEET1 has numbers from 1-31 across Row 1.  It has a list of cars in Column A (Ford, VW...).

SHEET2 has a list of cars in Column A, the day of the month in Column B and the condition in Column C (New, Used or Wreck).

I need to make a match on the car and the day of the month and then retrieve the condition.

For example:

SHEET2 has one row that shows:
Ford       8       New

SHEET1 shows at the intersection of Ford and 8 - "New".

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.  I have looked at VLOOKUP, INDEX and MATCH until I am blue in the face, but I can't figure this one out! I also looked through this site and couldn't find any similar scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What formulas have you tried so far What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: I didn't give any specific formulas because I had to turn everything generic as the sheets contain not only work-related information, but also more columns and rows than I gave in the example.  One of the examples I did use was =IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$40="Ford")*(Sheet2!$M$1:$M$40=AG$1))<1,Sheet2!I2,"") and this does work except for the fact that "I" is the column that the 'condition' appears in, so while I need to reference that column, I can't hard code a row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works (based on a scaled-down version I set up based on your data.

[image]

Array formula is: `=IFERROR(OFFSET($C$8,MATCH($A2&B$1,$A$9:$A$12&$B$9:$B$12,0),0),"")`

For array formulas to work be sure to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` instead of just `Enter` when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I created a new sheet exactly the same as yours and also created the same formula in cell B2.  I then dragged the cell to Column K and then down to Row 5 to copy the formula, however nothing shows up.  Everything in cells B2-K5 are empty (they show the formula, but no content).  Not sure what went wrong  :(

Comment: @lee - make sure to use an **Array** formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` instead of just `Enter`

Comment: That was it - you rock  :)  Thanks again.

Comment: A non Volatile version of your formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$9:$C$12,MATCH(1,($A$9:$A$12=$A2)*($B$9:$B$12=I$1),0)),"")`

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. I'm going to be ramping up on some Excel work again soon. I think I'll be studying all your answers as I go along to get some great formulas. I currently feel stuck in my knowledge :)

Comment: @ScottCraner When I try to insert the non volatile function into cell B2, I get "We found a problem with the formula.  Try clicking Insert Function...". When I click OK, it highlights $B$12.

Comment: @Lee Sometimes when posting the formula in a comment unprintable characters get inserted.  They are not visible to us, but excel reads them as an error.  Try typing the formula instead of pasting it.

Comment: Thanks, typing it manually did allow it to be accepted, it's just not producing any results after I drag the cell/formula across the table.

Comment: If I Ctrl+Shift+Enter then it shows just New in cell B2, whereas the New status should show in I2 for Ford.

Comment: This is what ultimately worked for me: 
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$9:$C$12,MATCH($A2 &B$1,$A$9:$A$12&$B$9:$B$12,0)),"")